# How to I get the array data from this piece of code?

Tags: php, arrays

```
class cstrike_statistics
{
    protected $hostname;
    protected $port;
    protected $playerinfo;
    protected $servervars;
    protected $serverrules;
    protected $errmsg;
    protected $timeout;
    protected $waittime;
    protected $serverCommands;

    public function cstrike_statistics()
    {
        $this->port                         = 27015;
        $this->timeout                      = 15;
        $this->waittime                     = 500;
        $this->serverCommands["players"]    = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x55";
        $this->serverCommands["rules"]      = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x56";
        $this->serverCommands["info"]       = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54";
    }

    public function setHostname($hostname)
    {
        $this->hostname = $hostname;
    }

    public function setPort($port)
    {
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    private function timenow()
    {
        return doubleval(ereg_replace('^0.([0-9]*) ([0-9]*)$', '2.1', microtime()));
    }

    private function getServerData($command)
    {
        $serverdata     = "";
        $serverdatalen  = 0;

        if (!$cssocket=@fsockopen("udp://".$this->hostname, $this->port, $errnr))
        {
            $this->errmsg="Unable to connect to target host";
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            socket_set_blocking($cssocket, true);
            @socket_set_timeout($cssocket, 0, 500000);

            fwrite($cssocket, $command, strlen($command));
            $starttime = $this->timenow();

            do
            {
                $serverdata .= fgetc($cssocket);
                $serverdatalen++;
                $socketstatus = socket_get_status($cssocket);

                if ($this->timenow() > ($starttime + $this->waittime))
                {
                    $this->errmsg = "Connection timed out";
                    fclose($cssocket);
                    return "";
                }

            } while ($socketstatus["unread_bytes"]);

            fclose($cssocket);
            return $serverdata;
        }
    }

    private function getnextstring(&$data)
    {
        $tmp     = "";
        $counter = 0;

        while (ord($data[$counter++])!=0) $tmp .= $data[$counter-1];
        $data = substr($data, strlen($tmp)+1);
        return $tmp;
    }

    private function getnextbytevalue(&$data)
    {
        $tmp  = ord($data[0]);
        $data = substr($data, 1);
        return $tmp;
    }

    private function getnextfragvalue(&$data)
    {
        $frags = ord($data[0])+(ord($data[1])<<8)+(ord($data[2])<<16)+(ord($data[3])<<24);
        if ($frags>=4294967294) $frags-=4294967296;
        $data = substr($data, 4);
        return $frags;
    }

    private function getnextplaytime(&$data)
    {
        $decnumber = ord($data[0])+(ord($data[1])<<8)+(ord($data[2])<<16)+(ord($data[3])<<24);
        $binnumber = base_convert($decnumber, 10, 2);
        while (strlen($binnumber) < 32) $binnumber = "0".$binnumber;
        $exp = abs(base_convert(substr($binnumber, 1, 8), 2, 10)) - 127;
        if (substr($binnumber, 0, 1) == "1") $exp = 0 - $exp;
        $man=1;
        $manadd=0.5;

        for ($counter=9; $counter<32; $counter++)
        {
            if (substr($binnumber, $counter, 1) == "1") $man += $manadd;
            $manadd = $manadd/2;
        }

        $time = round(pow(2, $exp) * $man);
        $playtime = "";
        if ($time>3600) $playtime = sprintf("%2dh", $time/3600);
        $time %= 3600;
        $playtime = $playtime.sprintf("%2dm", $time/60);
        $time %= 60;
        $playtime = $playtime.sprintf("%2ds", $time);
        $data = substr($data, 5);
        return $playtime;

    }

    public function getServerRules()
    {
        $serverdata = $this->getServerData($this->serverCommands["rules"]);
        if (strlen($serverdata)<5) return false;
        $rules = (ord($serverdata[5]))+(ord($serverdata[6])*256);
        if ($rules!=0)
        {
            $serverdata = substr($serverdata, 7);
            for ($i=1; $i<=$rules; $i++)
            {
                $this->serverrules[$this->getnextstring($serverdata)] = $this->getnextstring($serverdata);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getServerInfo()
    {
        $serverdata=$this->getServerData($this->serverCommands["info"]);
        if (strlen($serverdata)<5) return false;
        $serverdata=substr($serverdata,5);
        $this->servervars["serveraddress"]  = $this->getnextstring($serverdata);
        $this->servervars["servername"]     = $this->getnextstring($serverdata);
        $this->servervars["mapname"]        = $this->getnextstring($serverdata);
        $this->servervars["game"]           = $this->getnextstring($serverdata);
        $this->servervars["gamename"]       = $this->getnextstring($serverdata);
        $this->servervars["currentplayers"] = $this->getnextbytevalue($serverdata);
        $this->servervars["maxplayers"]     = $this->getnextbytevalue($serverdata);
        return true;
    }

    public function getServerPlayers()
    {
        $serverdata=$this->getServerData($this->serverCommands["players"]);
        if (strlen($serverdata)<5) return false;
        $players=ord($serverdata[5]);
        $serverdata=substr($serverdata,7);

        for ($i=1;$i<=$players;$i++)
        {
            $this->playerinfo[$i]["name"]       = $this->getnextstring($serverdata);
            $this->playerinfo[$i]["frags"]      = $this->getnextfragvalue($serverdata);
            $this->playerinfo[$i]["time"]       = $this->getnextplaytime($serverdata);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function getData()
    {

        $data = Array();

        $this->getServerInfo();
        $this->getServerPlayers();
        $this->getServerRules();

        $data['cstrike']['ServerInfo']  = $this->playerinfo;
        $data['cstrike']['ServerVars']  = $this->servervars;
        $data['cstrike']['ServerRules'] = $this->serverrules;

        return $data;
    }
}

$cstrike = new cstrike_statistics();
$cstrike->setHostname("206.212.247.10");
$cstrike->setPort(27015);

print_r($cstrike->getData());

?>
```

Output of this all is :

```
Array
(
    [cstrike] => Array
        (
            [ServerInfo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => I told Ya, i'll get Ya :)
                            [frags] => 103
                            [time] =>  1h42m 0s
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Black is Back {UA}
                            [frags] => 59
                            [time] =>  1h20m58s
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Chelsea FC
                            [frags] => 35
                            [time] =>  1h 1m15s
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => shadowd-m3
                            [frags] => 25
                            [time] => 14m46s
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => .Clem
                            [frags] => 18
                            [time] => 19m27s
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => minDsodom {dope herbs}
                            [frags] => 15
                            [time] => 12m50s
                        )
                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Lasa
                            [frags] => 10
                            [time] => 24m16s
                        )
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => memo
                            [frags] => 9
                            [time] => 40m49s
                        )
                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => :o
                            [frags] => 8
                            [time] =>  9m19s
                        )
                )
            [ServerVars] => Array
                (
                    [serveraddress] => 127.0.0.1:27015
                    [servername] => ]Si[ clan [nosteam|boosted] www.clan-si.com [chicago]
                    [mapname] => de_dust2
                    [game] => cstrike
                    [gamename] => NoSteam CS 1.6
                    [currentplayers] => 24
                    [maxplayers] => 32
                )
            [ServerRules] => Array
                (
                    [] => ????Em
                    [_tutor_bomb_viewable_check_interval] => 0.5
                    [_tutor_debug_level] => 0
                    [_tutor_examine_time] => 0.5
                    [_tutor_hint_interval_time] => 10.0
                    [_tutor_look_angle] => 10
                    [_tutor_look_distance] => 200
                    [_tutor_message_character_display_time_coefficient] => 0.07
                    [_tutor_message_minimum_display_time] => 1
                    [_tutor_message_repeats] => 5
                    [_tutor_view_distance] => 1000
                    [AdThemes] => v1.8 by Vet(3TT3V)
                    [aesp_version] => 1.4_beta
                    [afkslay_version] => 2.5.2
                    [allow_spectators] => 1.0
                    [amx_client_languages] => 0
                    [amx_nextmap] => de_cpl_mill
                    [amx_timeleft] => 00:00
                    [amxbans_version] => 5.0
                    [amxmodx_version] => 1.8.0.3660
                    [booster_version] => 1.36
                    [coop] => 0
                    [deathmatch] => 1
                    [decalfrequency] => 30
                    [DoNotShootTheHostages] => 0.2
                    [dp_version] => 0.4.1
                    [edgefriction] => 2
                    [hostage_debug] => 0
                    [hostage_stop] => 0
                    [humans_join_team] => any
                    [map_spawns] => T(20) CT(20)
                    [max_queries_sec] => 1
                    [max_queries_sec_global] => 1
                    [max_queries_window] => 1
                    [metamod_version] => 1.19
                    [mp_allowmonsters] => 0
                    [mp_autokick] => 0
                    [mp_autoteambalance] => 1
                    [mp_buytime] => 0.5
                    [mp_c4timer] => 45
                    [mp_chattime] => 10
                    [mp_consistency] => 1
                    [mp_fadetoblack] => 0
                    [mp_flashlight] => 1
                    [mp_footsteps] => 1
                    [mp_forcecamera] => 0
                    [mp_forcechasecam] => 0
                    [mp_fragsleft] => 0
                    [mp_freezetime] => 3
                    [mp_friendlyfire] => 0
                    [mp_ghostfrequency] => 0.1
                    [mp_hostagepenalty] => 13
                    [mp_kickpercent] => 0.66
                    [mp_limitteams] => 2
                    [mp_logdetail] => 0
                    [mp_logfile] => 1
                    [mp_logmessages] => 1
                    [mp_mapvoteratio] => 1
                    [mp_maxrounds] => 0
                    [mp_mirrordamage] => 0
                    [mp_playerid] => 0
                    [mp_roundtime] => 2.3
                    [mp_startmoney] => 1000
                    [mp_timeleft] => 0
                    [mp_timelimit] => 0
                    [mp_tkpunish] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

I just can't understand the code properly to get data from array.

Comment: What data you want to extract exactly. Everything in output is an array.

Comment: I've tidied up the code snippet up - use the 1010 button in the editor to do this.

Comment: Well, like players/maxplayers etc... ?
I know that output is array, i need to get information out of it now..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the code (after the class ends), replace the code by this:

```
$cstrike = new cstrike_statistics();
$cstrike->setHostname("206.212.247.10");
$cstrike->setPort(27015);

$result = $cstrike->getData();

//For maxplayers, do this:
echo "<h3>Maximum Players: ".$result['cstrike']['ServerVars']['maxplayers']."</h3>";

//For players do this:
foreach($result['cstrike']['ServerInfo'] as $players)
     echo "<h4>Player Name: ".$players['name']."</h4>";
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  , still getting this error :(

Comment: Actually, its kinda working... http://www.mg.rps.ee/serveripank/getdata/cs-getdata.php    Look at the bottom of the page..

Comment: @Kristjan, yes it is working. I have slightly updated it so it looks better. Use this code now. Rest you can work out yourself. If you need any specific variable out of it, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to read through the manual page on arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I already read it... Doesnt help me very well, if i cant understand the code i posted... The basics of arrays i somewhat understand but i cant figure out the code ... Even my friend tried to figure out... :S

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
$obj = $cstrike->getData();
echo "players count : " . count($obj['cstrike']['ServerInfo']) . "<br/>";
echo "Player1 Name: " . $obj['cstrike']['ServerInfo'][0]['name'] . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thank you, but Shamittomar already helped me out with this.. :)